# Jolt Transformation - Match Values in Separate Branches - JSON

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to achieve the following JSON transformation using Jolt processor in Nifi

Input JSON

```
{
    "topLevel": {
        "secondLevelA": {
            "thirdLevelA": [
                {
                    "norsemen": "huntinSouth",
                    "value": "AAA"
                },
                {
                    "norsemen": "huntinNorth",
                    "value": "BBB"
                }
                ]
        },
        "secondLevelB": {
            "thirdLevelB": [
                {
                    "norsemen": "huntinNorth",
                    "oddCode": "AAA301"
                },
                {
                    "norsemen": "huntinNorth",
                    "oddCode": "BBB701"
                },
                {
                    "norsemen": "huntinWest",
                    "oddCode": "AAA701"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Output JSON

```
{
    "NAME": [
        {
            "norsemen": "huntinSouth",
            "value": "AAA",
            "refValue": []
        },
        {
            "norsemen": "huntinNorth",
            "value": "BBB",
            "refValue": [
                {
                    "oddCode": [
                        "BBB701"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to test for matches between the values of  **secondLevelA.thirdLevelA.norsemen** and **secondLevelB.thirdLevelB.norsemen**. If one or more matches is found, all values of **secondLevelB.thirdLevelB.oddCode** contained in the same set as the matching norsemen would be placed in the output in the same set as the corresponding matching norsemen.

Is there a way to do this using existing Jolt Operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you have some non-declarative logic that could not be covered with jolt.

[From jolt description:](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt#Overview)

**Jolt :**

- focuses on transforming the structure of your JSON data, not manipulating specific values

  - The idea being: use Jolt to get most of the structure right, then write code to fix values

**The Stock transforms are:**

```
shift       : copy data from the input tree and put it the output tree
default     : apply default values to the tree
remove      : remove data from the tree
sort        : sort the Map key values alphabetically ( for debugging and human readability )
cardinality : "fix" the cardinality of input data.  Eg, the "urls" element is usually a List, but if there is only one, then it is a String
```

---

I don't see here kind of `if/then/else`

So, I think your task could not be covered with just `jolt`

for me the easiest way will be script processor with JavaScript or Groovy language.