# Error when posting JSON using NiFi vs. curl

Tags: json, curl, apache-nifi

I am seeing a very slight difference between how NiFi's **InvokeHTTP** processor POSTs json data and how **curl** does it.

The problem is that the data APPEARS to be the same when I log it ... but the data is rendering differently.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? Thank you!

**CURL** -- works; correct printout & render

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "responseID": "a1b2c3", "responseData": { "signals": [ "a", "b", "c" ] } } localhost:8998/userInput`

***WebServer app printout***

responseID: `a1b2c3`

responseData: `{signals=[a, b, c]}`

***Template render***

[image: Template render / output for CURL]

**NiFi** -- does not work; correct printout BUT incorrect render

1. Generate FlowFile
2. UpdateAttributes
   [image: UpdateAttributes Configuration]
3. AttributesToJSON
4. InvokeHTTP

***WebServer app printout***

responseID: `a1b2c3`

responseData: `{signals=[a, b, c]}`

***Template render***
[image: Template render / output for NiFi]

Answer (score 2):

you need this kind of json:

```js
{ "responseID": "a1b2c3", "responseData": { "signals": [ "a", "b", "c" ] } }
```

but in nifi you building this:

```js
{ "responseID": "a1b2c3", "responseData": "{ signals=[ a, b, c ] }" }
```

it means that you create `responseData` just as a string `"{ signals=[ a, b, c ] }"` but you need an object

in nifi the AttributesToJSON processor creates only one level object, so you can create a sequence of `AttributesToJSON -> EvaluateJsonPath -> AttributesToJSON` to make nested json objects.

or use `ExecuteStript` with `javascript` or `groovy` language - both has good syntax to build json.

Comment: I'll give this a try.  I had been building the NiFi JSON like `{ "signals": [ "a", "b", "c" ] } }`, but it was interpreting it as a string ... which goes to your "one level object" point.

Comment: I read something about the JoltTransformJSON processor ... is there any way for NiFi to programmatically handle dynamic, multi-level JSON?

Comment: programmatically - it's `ExecuteScript` processor. check for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335048/nifi-how-to-change-value-of-json/44386883#44386883

Comment: Jolt - has some limitations check if it's acceptable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169511/jolt-transformation-match-values-in-separate-branches-json/44197932#44197932